# How to SELECT an especifc row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables which are:

[Users table [image: Users table]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDShe.png) 
[Subjects table [image: Subjects table]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dNmR.png) 
[Files table [image: Files table]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3Sere.png)

I want to **SELECT** the files from a certain user, for example, I have the user Toninho (uti_id=2), he has a subject called Ed.Fisica (dis_id=4) and inside the subject he has 2 files which are Voley and Basket. 
To SELECT those files I thought about using this condition:

```sql
SELECT trab_id, trab_nome, trab_file, trab_notas, trab_dis_id 
FROM trabalhos, disciplinas, utilizadores 
WHERE trabalhos.trab_dis_id = disciplinas.dis_id = 4 AND disciplina.dis_uti_id = utilizadores.uti_id = 2
```

But it doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need JOIN statements added.

```
SELECT 
t.* 
FROM trabalhos t 
LEFT JOIN disciplinas d on d.dis_id = t.trab_dis_id
LEFT JOIN utilizadores u on u.uti_id = d.dis_uti_id
WHERE u.uti_id = 2;
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe you need to use joins. You can find more info about them here: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp.

For your case, I think this should work

```
select t1.*, t2.*, t3.*
from user_table as t1
left join second_table as t2
on t1.uti_id = t2.dis_uti_id
left join third_table as t3
on t2.dis_id = t3.trab_dis_id
where uti_id = 2
```

If you want to bring in everyone, you can just comment the where statement.

As I don't know what columns are in each table, I just use * to bring in everything from that tables. You can just remove and manually put specific columns that you want in the select statement.